# How to open a file using filepath and argv[] in c++?

Tags: c++, file, command-line, argv

I have a text file which is specified as command line input in the path /home/project/.
How do I open the file using ifstream by specifying the path and taking the file name from argv[]?

Currently I am trying as below;

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   ifstream fin;
   stringstream file_path;
   string file;
   file_path << "/home/project/" << argv[1];
   file = file_path.str();
   fin.open(file)  //not working
..
}
```

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: What is not working?? Is there an error??

Comment: Yes, it throws an error. "No matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)"

Comment: Then compile with the command line option `-std=c++11` or go with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
fin.open(file.c_str());
```

Alternatively you can compile your file with `-std=c++11`, because starting with C++11 `ifstream` supports getting the file name in a string. See reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/).